# How to export Azure log analytics data into an SQL database?

Tags: azure, tableau-api, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

We need the Log Analytics data in a SQL database for use in Tableau. How can we do this?

Answer (score 2):

Log files are saved in Azure Storage Account, if you read the following article I think that you solve your problem.

[Connect to Azure Blob Storage (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-azure-blob-storage-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

You can use log search feature to export log data to SQL database:

1. Perform a Log Search from your log analytics workspace
2. Create a runbook to import Log Search results to SQL Server

Comment: Is that one time only? Or can you set it up to export it every x time?