# Transfer data from Azure monitor to Azure SQL database

Tags: logging, azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-monitoring

We are logging the data in Azure monitor (under Log Analytics workspace) from databricks. We are looking for reporting these details through one of the reporting platforms that required the data to be stored in database.

Is there anyway we can pull this data from Log Analytics workspace to Azure SQL?

This is critical and looking for some help or documentation around this.

Comment: Check out this .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199059/how-to-export-azure-log-analytics-data-into-an-sql-database

Comment: In nutshell,
1) use powershell fire the log analytics query 
2) Get the ouput of step 1 and  perform a normal insert like any SQL Server DB.